# Display all the buffers in all the open vim Windows?

Tags: buffers

There's this really great feature in Firefox, where you can search all the open tabs by typing `%` and then typing what open tab you are searching for.

Is it possible to do something similar to this with all the open gvim windows?

Comment: Not clear. Do you want to search all gvim windows (like separate instances of gvim)? Or buffers opened in all separate gvims? Or just buffers in a single instance of gvim? Or window splits in gvim? Or ....

Comment: All the open instances.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to coordinate between multiple instances of gvim, short of custom programs/plugins/etc. all reading/writing the same file. OTOH, `getbufinfo()->filter({_, v -> !v.hidden})` will give you all the buffers currently not hidden.